# Error "Your user name and password are not defined" when creating a Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to use `isql.exe` to create a new database, but I running into some errors. After running `isql`, here is the command that I put in.

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting errors when trying to create a new db. I am using Firebird 2.5. Could someone give me a clue on what to do next?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual data. Post the actual text in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that your password is incorrect (or that the SYSDBA user doesn't exist, but that is unlikely). You need to use the correct password. Likely you specified a password in the installer.

If you don't know the correct password, it is not possible to change it with Firebird 2.5 on Windows (unless you have an account with the `RDB$ADMIN` role and know that password). You will need to replace the security2.fdb with one that has a known password, e.g. from the [Firebird 2.5](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) zip download, where it is 'masterkey' (or actually, 'masterke'). However, be aware that doing this will make you lose all other users and passwords as well.

See also [Forgot the username and password of *fdb (firebird) database. Is there anyway I can crack this database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512325/forgot-the-username-and-password-of-fdb-firebird-database-is-there-anyway-i)

As an aside, if you're new to Firebird, I would recommend starting with [Firebird 4.0](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/) instead. Firebird 2.5 is end-of-life.

Comment: i tried downloading the zip and took out the security2.fdb file and replaced it with other one. I was still unable to access the fdb. I also saw the link, I was not able to get it to work either. any other suggestions?

Comment: @PeterSun If replacing the security2.fdb didn't solve the problem, then something weird is going on, because that should work. Do you have multiple installations of Firebird running on your system? Maybe you replaced the wrong one. Also, how did you replace it? Given it is in C:\Program Files it needs to be copied with administrator privileges, otherwise the file ends up in the virtual store of your user profile, which can't be seen if Firebird is run as a service.

Comment: @PeterSun In any case, it might make sense to ask your question on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) instead. Maybe someone that doesn't frequent Stack Overflow has an idea, and email/Google Groups is also more suitable for the back and forth of troubleshooting.